# Sum of values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

My list of dictionaries

```
[{'key': '', 'value': 494}, {'key': 'cloud', 'value': 63}, {'key': 'cloud', 'value': 44}]
```

As you can see, my list contains two dictionaries with "key": "cloud". I want to find those duplicates and make a sum out of them.

My desired output:

```
    [{'key': '', 'value': 494}, {'key': 'cloud', 'value': 107}]
```

How can I sum up values in a list of dictionaries with the same key?

Comment: You may want to research it first: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sum-list-of-dictionaries-with-same-key/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [{'key': '', 'value': 494}, {'key': 'cloud', 'value': 63}, {'key': 'cloud', 'value': 44}]

total = defaultdict(int)
for e in lst:
    total[e["key"]] += e["value"]

res = [{"key" : key, "value" : value} for key, value in total.items()]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'key': '', 'value': 494}, {'key': 'cloud', 'value': 107}]
```